# need an php loop for existing condition

Tags: php, arrays

I am looking for a PHP solution to use a loop to go through to capture all the data

Here is an example of a lookup without using a loop

```
if (array_key_exists('utf8String', $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][0][0]['value'])) {
    // do somthing
} else if (array_key_exists('printableString', $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][0][0]['value'])) {
    // do somthing
} else if (array_key_exists('bmpString', $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][0][0]['value'])) {
    // do somthing
} else if (array_key_exists('telextexString', $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][0][0]['value'])) {
    // do somthing
}
```

I need the loop to go through the entire array. For **ONLY** the first [ ] the loop should increase the integer [0] to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJmBc.png), [2] and so forth until its gone through the whole lot. In case you are wondering, the second [ ] is always [0] so that needs to remain as is.

Right now I am copying/pasting the above about 20 times and manually updating the number in the first box but I am hoping there is a more elegant way to achieve that.

-- MORE CONTEXT --

[image]

-- WORKING CODE -- offered by @Ghost

```
$count = count($cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence']);
$exists = array('utf8String', 'printableString', 'teletexString');
$oid = array('id-at-stateOrProvinceName', 'id-at-countryName', 'id-at-localityName', 'id-at-commonName', 'id-at-organizationalUnitName');
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    foreach($exists as $field) {
        if(array_key_exists($field, $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value'])) {
            $value = $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value'][$field];
            echo $value, ' [',$field, ']',"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to use a foreach loop (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: Use a foreach on your array and then your tests in your loop ?

Comment: Could you please provide samples of what may be included in `$cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][0][0]['value']` etc.? Presume the `['value']` is an associative array since you use `array_key_exists()` on it? I'm not getting the full picture of what you're dealing with here...

Comment: could be any of these: 'utf8String', 'printableString', 'bmpString', 'telextexString'.. As an example the path looks like this _$cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][0][0]['value']['utf8String']_

Comment: basically, what i am trying to do is check what type of encoding is set if it's  utf8String or printableString etc.. then set that as a variable.. the variable should be the value 'utff8String' or whatever key was found.. hope that makes sense

Comment: i updated my post to give a visual explanation of what i am trying to achieve. Please see the attached image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add another loop inside applying each field into `array_key_exists`, this applies to @Markus' idea anyway:

```
$count = count($cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence']);
$exists = array('utf8String', 'printableString', 'teletexString');
$oid = array('id-at-stateOrProvinceName', 'id-at-countryName', 'id-at-localityName', 'id-at-commonName', 'id-at-organizationalUnitName');
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

    foreach($exists as $field) {
        if(array_key_exists($field, $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value'])) {
            $value = $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value'][$field];
            $k = array_keys($cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['type']);
            $oid = reset($k);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I will try this out now and report back

Comment: That'd certainly do it. Could also use `array_intersect()` between the `$cert[...]` array and the `$exists` values, and then use a `switch` to cater for the actions for each match case.

Comment: just to make sure the solution provided will work. i updated my post to give a visual explanation of what i am trying to achieve. Please see the attached image

Comment: @user3436467 nice, i wish more questions would be like this :D lol, anyway, just use `$field` under the `foreach` loop if you want further processing

Comment: your code is working perfectly. However, i have one more hopefully small tweak i hope you can update your code.. I have updated my post to show the working code and on the third line I added an extra array $oid.. the path to this array is `if(array_key_exists($field, $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['type'])) {` i want to return the $oid value from the loop same as you did with $field but couldnt work it out

Comment: note, the $oid value falls under ['type'] not ['value'] -- i want to echo the ['type'] value. So i end up with `echo $oid, $value, ' [',$field, ']',"\n";`

Comment: @user3436467 is it possible you could put the `var_export($cert)` into pastebin, i'd like to try your data, try pastebin, just set it to public

Comment: i am using phpseclib with my php to return certificate data.. might be better if you go here: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/decoder.php and then hit the decode button.. you will see the data i am trying to return

Comment: your code works perfectly as is but i just want it to include the value from this path as well `$cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['type']` -- note ['type'] this time..

Comment: @user3436467 how is this applied anyway? there is no corresponding value under type, just that key

Comment: @user3436467 anyway i edited the answer, try out the revision, can't seem to understand what to do next, just guess by a long shot

Comment: correct i want the name of the key i.e the first one in [0]['type'] is _id-at-countryName_

Comment: @user3436467 is that really a key? `[$i][0]['type']['id-at-localityName']`, if yes, then `array_keys` would get that

Comment: does not seem to be working.. hmm now i am not sure if i should be setting an array to return the ['type'] value as that value could be anything and i need to return it the same way your returning $field . can we join a chat to quickly discuss

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75520/discussion-between-user3436467-and-ghost).

Answer (score 1):

[ **EDIT**: Please see the comments below. ] How about for simples...

```
$strings = ['utf8String', 'printableString' ... ];

foreach ($strings as $string) { // do your checks etc. }
```

I suppose you know how to increment a counter in a loop. `$i++` and stuff, use `[$i]` wherever you need to increment the reference value in your `$cert` array. On match, `break` or `continue` in place of `else if`, depending on what exactly you need to accomplish here. Your objectives aren't too clear in the question, could share a bit more insight...

Comment: I know how to do it in javascript `for (var i = 0; i < string.something.length; i++) { var data = string.something[i];` but i am completely newbie to php

Comment: i updated my post to give a visual explanation of what i am trying to achieve. Please see the attached image

Comment: Thanks for the helpful clarification! Now, you don't actually need to run all those comparisons in a loop of possibilities.... You can simply: `$string_type = implode( array_keys($cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value']) );` -- and that'll give you the key defined under `...['value']`. (Presuming there's only one key-value pair under each entry.)